# Install mvn in service mix could not be resolved

Tags: maven, apache-servicemix

I want to install a service to service Mix using syntax:

smx@root>install mvn:id.co.ess/endpoint-ptr04
java.lang.RuntimeException: URL [mvn:id.co.ess/endpoint-ptr04] could not be resolved.

What's wrong with my service mix, how can I resolve the problem.
Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Maven URLs have syntax: **mvn:group-id/artifact-id/version**, such as:

```
install mvn:commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6
```

Also the version of ServiceMix + information if you're behind proxy could be crutial.